# Find coding mistake

Tags: perl

```
sub main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    my $j = '@b(defgh|jk3m#9pqr$+uvwxy2';

    for ( int $i = 0; $i < 32; ++$i ) {
        print (grep {/\S/} split('\W|', $j))[$i % (split('', $j))[11] + $i % (split('',$j))[25] * $i % 19];
    }

    print "\n";

    return 0;
}

main() unless caller;
```

Where is my mistake? I can't find it. but I know that it's probably inside the `for` loop

Comment: To clarify why this question was closed: we shouldn't be trying to guess what the "mistake" is. We have no idea what this code is supposed to do in the first place. What you should clearly present in the question, _besides_ the code in question, is 1) what you expect the code to do, 2) what are the exact errors, if any, 3) what makes the result wrong, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to write perl using C constructs.

1. Use `strict` and `warnings` to help you catch common mistakes.
2. Remove C construct `int argc, char *argv[]`.
3. Remove C construct `int $i=0;$i<32;++$i`, you can write C-style loops in perl, but it is not very perlish.
4. Break long complex expressions into parts so you can debug the parts easily.
5. `main unless caller` is an odd construction.  If you intend to use this as a library, do not call your function `main`, and read up on `perldoc perlmod`.
6. One-letter variables are usually terrible and should be better renamed.
7. Using magic numbers in your code is error-prone, there is no way of knowing if they are correct.
8. There are further improvements which can be made, including moving the split statements outside of the loop.

Rewriting your code, I get the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

main();

sub main {
    my $j = '@b(defgh|jk3m#9pqr$+uvwxy2';
    for my $i ( 0 .. 31 ) {
        my @characters = grep { /\S/ } split /\W|/, $j;

        my ($first_mod)  = (split//,$j)[11];
        my $first_index  = $i % $first_mod;

        my ($second_mod) = (split//,$j)[25];
        my $second_index = $i % $second_mod * $i % 19;

        print $characters[ $first_index + $second_index ];
    }
    print "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
beefdkb3emdrbuevd2bdeedjbke3dqbr
```

**Further Reading**

[perldoc perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html)

[perldoc perltrap C/C++ traps](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap.html#C%2FC%2B%2B-Traps)

Comment: Well.. I Liked the clean and tidy representation..! Thanks for sharing.